# Can someone please tell me what this poem means?

Tags: translation, meaning, traditional-characters, poetry

Can any one tell me the meaning of this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a poem by 李白 (Li Bai 701 AD -762 AD )

> 一為遷客去長沙，Once became a banished man, he headed to Changsha.
>
> 西望長安不見家。looking back at Chang'an in the west, he could not see his home.
>
> 黃鶴樓中吹玉笛，Inside the Yellow Crane Tower, someone was playing a *tunes with jade flute.
>
> 江城五月落梅花。It felt like falling plum blossoms in the River City in May

*The tunes was《梅花落》(Plum Blossom Falling)

Li Bai was banished from the capital, He wrote this poem to express his sorrow.

Comment: Li Bai  had been demoted in his life,  that's why I presumed the character in the poem was Li Bai himself. It is now changed to non-specific person in my translation. (Since 賈誼's name was not mentioned in the poem  itself.) thanks user-487 for pointing it out.

Comment: Thankk youu tang ho 